# looping through Hashmap with Iterator

Tags: java, java-8, hashmap, iterator

i am trying to to calculating sum of mod of all values of a hashmap in java 8. but it is not providing as supposed to. below is the code i have written.

```
private static int FindPairs(int n,int[] ar) {
    Map<Integer, Integer> countermap=new HashMap<>();
    Iterator<Integer> itr=countermap.keySet().iterator();
    int result =0;
    for(int i=0;i<ar.length;i++) {
        if(countermap.containsKey(ar[i])) {
            countermap.put(ar[i], countermap.get(ar[i])+1);
        }
        else {
            countermap.put(ar[i], 1);
        }
    }
    int mod=0;

    while(itr.hasNext()) {
        System.out.println(itr.next());
        mod=itr.next()%2;
        result=result + mod;
    }
    System.out.println(Arrays.asList(countermap));
    return result;
}
```

input:

ar= {1,2,3,4,5,6,1,3,4,5}

n=7

output:

[{1=2, 2=1, 3=2, 4=2, 5=2, 6=1}]

0

Comment: Why is `n` never used anywhere? Also can you clarify what you're expecting please?

Comment: Isn't the `n` unused in the method!?

Comment: Yes I have used array.length while troubleshooting.
I am trying to counter the pairs possible in a given array for repeated values.

Comment: The first loop can be written as simple as `for(int value: ar) countermap.marge(value, 1, Integer::sum);` then the second `for(int next: countermap.keySet()) { System.out.println(next); result += next % 2; }` and for the final print statement, there is no need to wrap the map in a list, `System.out.println(countermap);` will do, unless the `[` and `]` around the output are crucial.

Comment: sysout is just for the troubleshooting purpose only. plus i want to work on the values not keys keyset() will return a set of keys from map. basically i want to traverse the map looking for the mod of (value%2) and adding that up in result variable

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I have found two problems in the code you posted

1. Your iterator has to be created *after* your `HashMap` has been filled. Otherwise, it will always be empty

   ```
   Iterator<Integer> itr = countermap.keySet().iterator(); <---- HERE
   while (itr.hasNext()) {
       System.out.println(itr.next());
       mod = itr.next()% 2;
       result = result + mod;
   }
   ```
2. Also, calling `itr.next()` twice in a row will just skip one all the time. You should call it once, store it in a variable, and then use it twice if you want

   ```
   Iterator<Integer> itr = countermap.keySet().iterator();
   while (itr.hasNext()) {               _
       Integer next = itr.next();         |
       System.out.println(next);           }<---- HERE
       mod = next % 2;                   _|
       result = result + mod;
   }
   ```

With those changes, the output becomes the following

```
1
2
3
4
5
6
[{1=2, 2=1, 3=2, 4=2, 5=2, 6=1}]
3
```

Comment: I think the problem was having iterator declaration before hashmap thanks

Comment: Or just use the standard loop idiom, `for(Integer next: countermap.keySet()) { System.out.println(next); mod = next % 2; result = result + mod; }` which guides to the correct use of a local variable automatically.